# "Alcohol-free" event

Tags: translation

Is there a word for "***alcohol-free*** event", as in a social event, like a party, where alcohol is not served?

Answer (score 5):

It would be either 飲酒禁止のイベント (if alcohol is explicitly prohibited) or お酒が出ないイベント (if "alcohol is not served" is all what you want to imply). I know it's not short, but "`X`-free" is often difficult to translate to Japanese.

"Alcohol-free beer" is ノンアルコールビール, and "sugar-free gum" is 無糖ガム, シュガーフリーガム, 砂糖の入っていないガム, etc., by the way.

Comment: Thank you. The meaning I'm looking for is "alcohol-free" as in people willingly abstaining from alcohol. I guess the closest would be "お酒が出ない"? I have also seen "ノンアルコールパーティー", but most results with "ノンアルコール" are about the physical drinks.

Comment: お酒が出ないパーティー is OK if it's held in a restaurant, but if you're thinking of a home party where participants brings food and drink, it will be お酒なしのパーティー, お酒を飲まないパーティー, etc. (出る ≒ "served")

Comment: @user99074 Using ノンアル（コール） to describe "don't serve alcohol" is fairly understandable and doesn't strike me weird, except in formal writings.